# Android how to clear fragment backstack from a particular range

Tags: android

Is it possible to clear the backstack entry from a particular range ie , if backstack entry size is 10 then is it possible to remove backstackentry from 5 to 7

Answer (score 1):

Using `popBackStack(int,int)` or `popBackStack(String,int)` with [FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE) might work.

Comment: I have check the method FragmentManger and what am understands that it's not possible to remove fragments within a particular range but we can remove n number of fragment starting from end

Answer (score 0):

You can use [popBackStack(int,int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack%28int,%20int%29) to pop up to a certain fragement but nothing in the documentation about ranges.

Might be time to rethink the problem ... sounds like your UI design is flying in the face of the intended use of the OS